# Reference to an option versus option of a reference

Tags: rust

I'm wondering if there's any difference (in terms of optimization) between a function that takes as argument:

```rust
fn thing(a: &Option<T>)
```

versus a function that takes as argument:

```rust
fn thing(a: Option<&T>)
```

Comment: I think the second one will force you to clone `a` if `a` is already an `Option<&T>`. But the alternative might be compiled to a clone anyway

Comment: Note that it's possible to convert `Option<T>` or `&Option<T>` to `Option<&T>`  via `as_ref`. It's also possible to convert `Option<&T>` to `Option<T>` with `copied` (if `T: Copy`) or `cloned`.

Comment: There are many possible answers here, depending on what `T` is, and depending on if you care about optimizations currently available or about all possible optimizations.

Comment: You may want to check here for some guarantees about Option's size: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/#representation Notably, `Option<&T>` has the same size as `&T`.

Answer (score 11):

Use `Option<&T>`

As noted in the comments, `Option<&T>` is the same size as `&T`, so there's no real difference between them in terms of calling convention. The `&Option<T>` has a slight cost that you're forced to follow an indirection before being able to match on the value, but I wouldn't seriously consider a reason for one vs the other except in the most dire of circumstances.

However, the biggest difference is that `&Option<T>` has an ergonomics problem. Consider the case that I have a `T` that I want to pass to this function:

```
let t: T = ...;
thing(&Some(T));
```

This isn't so bad, but what if I wanted to use my `t` afterwards? I can't with the above code since it was *moved* in order to make the `Option<T>`. I would be forced to do something like this:

```
let t: T = ...;
let opt_t = Some(t);
thing(&opt_t );
let t = opt_t.unwrap();
```

Which isn't very nice. Moving the variable itself may also have a non-negligible cost even if I didn't want to use it afterwards. An `Option<&T>` argument would not have these problems.

Comment: As a counterargument, many times you get `&Option<T>` (usually because of generics), and converting it has some cost. However I agree with your reasoning.